# Accessing controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

I have create a custom directive that displays the directive template within the current view:

```
<div class="upper-outfits-layer" ng-show="outfitExpanded">
    <expanded-outfit outfit="outfits[currentOutfit]"></expanded-outfit>
</div>
```

That will display an html template. The view this directive is placed within, has its own controller. I need to access the views scope variables from this directive and vice versa.

Is it possible to access a sperate controller from a custom directive?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use isolated scope in your directive. You can directly get access your view scope.
2. (In case of Isolated scope) Pass the variables in the attribute of your directive. They will be accessible to your directive through your isolated scope.
3. (In case of Isolated scope) Use scope.$parent in your directive to access view scope.

Comment: I'm more agreeing with your second bullet point here, since the directive should be a standalone component, and if it requires anything else, the view dependent on it can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't isolate the directive's scope using scope:{}, you should be able to access parent controller's variables. Maybe add the directive code to your question if the problem persists...